# Is it possible for python's tarfile function addfile to not read all data into memory?

Tags: python, tar

I'm trying to tar a lot files between s3 bucket using python:

```py
    input_stream = get_stream_from_origin_s3()

    tar_stream = BytesIO()
    tar = tarfile.open(mode="w:gz", fileobj=tar_stream)
    info = tarfile.TarInfo(name="a.txt")
    info.size = size_of_input_stream
    tar.addfile(info, input_stream)
    tar_stream.seek(0)

    save_tar_stream_to_destination_s3(tar_stream)
```

My problem is that tarfile's addfile reads all the data into memory `tar.addfile(info, input_stream)` instead of in save_tar_stream_to_destination_s3 which causes for me huge memory consumption.

In bash I could simply do something like this:

```sh
tar -czf - big-dir | ssh user@host 'cat > /path/to/big-dir.tar.gz'
```

Comment: You do know that, as it's written, `tar_stream` is also going to hold the entire tar file in memory before you save it out to S3, right?

Comment: You're telling `tar` to write to an in-memory buffer, where else than "in memory" would it put the compressed data exactly?

Comment: @Thomas  Yes and I want to avoid this. But I don't know if ti's possible in python.

Comment: Write to an actual file then give that to `save_tar_stream_to_destination_s3`?

Comment: @Masklinn Good point. I could pass S3 stream to save_tar_stream_to_destination_s3 instead of BytesIO.

Comment: Yeah if you can straight get a writable s3 stream that'd work, though in that case you may need to use `w|gz`, according to the doc this is the mode necessary to avoid random seeking (see the second table of [tarfile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open)).